# Remplazar o eliminar html en mysql update

Tags: php, mysql, update

Tengo cientos de post con un código de tabla de contenido  que quiero eliminar mediante una consulta sql desde phpmyadmin.
El código es más o menos este:

```html
<p>Contenido</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="#Title_1">Title 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#PTitle_2">Title 2.</a></li>
<li><a href="#Title_3">Title 3.</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#Title_1">Title 1.</a></li>
<li><a href="#Title_2">Title 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#Title_3">Title 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Como puedo eliminar o editar con la sentencia update replace el div toc:_container con todo lo que tenga dentro, incluyendo el mismo div con su etiqueta de cierre por supuesto.
intento hacer algo asi :

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo = REPLACE(campo,'<div id="toc_container">.....</div>',' ....');
```

Le agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Por favor agregue qué ha intentado para eliminar esos *posts*. Según el HTML que colocó, ¿que quiere borrar. los elementos internos de `Title1` o el `Title1` que no tiene elementos anidados? - [edit] y aclare esto en la pregunta.

Comment: quiero eliminar todo lo que esta dentro del <div id=toc_container></div>

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `strip_tags()` desde php.

Elimina las etiquetas contenidas en un string.

También por seguridad puedes usar `real_escape_string()` antes de actualizar la base.

Tal parece intentabas "scrapear".